# "Missing architecture. Apps built with Watch OS 5.0 and later SDKs must contain additional architectures."

Tags: ios, iphone, ios10, xcode10.2, watchos-5

When I am trying to upload the app to appstoreConnect, it fails with below error:

> ERROR ITMS-90733: "Missing architecture. Apps built with Watch OS 5.0 and later SDKs must contain additional architectures.
>
> the iOS version: iOS 10
> the WatchOS version: WatchOS 3
>
> the Build Setting "Valid Architectures" for iOS is "arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s"
>
> the Build Setting "Valid Architectures" for watchOS is "arm64_32 armv7k"

Has anyone got a similar error?

Comment: Making build using what xcode version ?

Comment: build is done using Xcode 10.2

Answer (score 2):

After updating to MacOS Catalina, to be able to continue updating Xcode and get the latest version 11.4, I ran into this problem for one of my two apps. One would upload but the other kept getting this error.

I compared their Build Settings.

For the iOS Target in Build Settings I had to add `arm64e` to "Valid Architectures". It should have 4. "`arm64,arm64e,armv7,armv7e`"

EDIT: Remove all of them. Replace with `$(VALID_ARCHS)` which auto-fills with the currently supported valid architectures.

For the two WatchOS Targets it should have 2. "`arm64_32,armv7k`"
In my App the WatchOS Targets had the same cpu architectures as iOS.
Now it uploads fine to iTC.

Answer (score 1):

Please check (For iOS app target) the `Build settings -> search valid architecture -> Valid architecture` it should be the `arm64 arm64e armv7 armv7s`

[image]

For the Watch OS target so the same and set the `Valid architecture` to `arm64_32 armv7k`

Comment: for both iOS and watchOS app target was set to suggested one. still the same error is coming.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer. As you said adding these 4 to the valid architectures of all of my targets (Main app and widget) and arm54_32 and armv7k to the watch and watch extensions solved the issue. I also kept the main Architectures as $(ARCHS_STANDARD).  Hope this helps someone :) I spent a whole day on this